# azure cli 2.0 how to add inbound-nat-rule?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

As title, I tried to do that with following command:

```
az network nic ip-config inbound-nat-rule add --ip-config-name default-ip-config 
  -g <resource_group> --nic-name <nic_name>  --inbound-nat-rule 
  subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<rg_name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/<lb_name>/inboundNatRules/<nat_rule_name>
```

then I got the following:

```
NoneType' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/goodwill/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 37, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/Users/goodwill/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 157, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/Users/goodwill/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 343, in _execute_command
    raise ex
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Anyone has idea whats going wrong?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in new azure cli 2.0. The exact same command works in the old Xplat-CLI:

`azure network nic ip-config inbound-nat-rule create -g <resource_group> -l <lb_name> -r <nat_rule_name> -c <nic_name>`

Comment: Do you mean you want to add load balancer inbound-nat-rule use Cli2.0?

Comment: No- after you add the rule you need to do the association from the nic end to add the nic private IP to the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after you add the rule you need to do the association from the nic end
>   to add the nic private IP to the rule

There are some difference between old Xplat-CLI and CLI 2.0, here is the script to associate a **existing** NIC to the load balancer NAT rules:

```
az network nic ip-config update -g vm --nic-name nic-name --name ipconfigname --lb-name lbname --lb-inbound-nat-rules natrule
```

If you want to create a new VM NIC to this NAT rules, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-create-cli-complete#create-an-nic-to-use-with-the-linux-vm)

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Works perfect, I was going thru the verification before I accept the answer :)